# Jira and TFS integration?

Tags: plugins, jira, tfsintegrationplatform

Does anybody know of an plugin that can be used to integrate Jira with TFS?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? TFS has an issue tracker for itself, what would you like to do when the integration is done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining TFS with Jira - any experiences or advice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810660/combining-tfs-with-jira-any-experiences-or-advice)

Answer (score 7):

See [Combining TFS with Jira - any experiences or advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810660/combining-tfs-with-jira-any-experiences-or-advice)

The options are as follows:

> - [TFS4JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.spartez.jira.plugins.bork.tfs4jira) (commercial / free for personal & non profit use)
> - [UseTFS](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pigsty.jira.plugin.usetfs) (commercial / free for community and open-source projects)
> - [Atlassian Connector for Visual Studio](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/PLVS) (free)

**Disclosure**: I work for the UseTFS vendor Pigsty.

Comment: Please take care when promoting your product, see the respective FAQ [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for details. PS: I appreciate that you have included your contenders this time around, however, omitting the link to the non commercial option is not exactly helping your reputation in this regard, nor is omitting the disclosure again, which you have been kindly asked to include as well already.

Comment: Hi Steffen. I'm new to Stackoverflow and do appologize for not complying with rules. Finally I get to read the full comment as previous ones seem to be removed and I only got to see "Please take care when promoting your product, see the respective FAQ May I promote products or we..."As for the link to non commercial option - I was not allowed to make answer with more than two links due to low reputation.

Comment: I had actually been surprised that you could create links at all and wasn't aware of the 2 link limitation meanwhile in place apparently, my apologies for that! Thanks much for your consideration, and welcome to Stack Overflow :) And good luck with your product of course, _UseTFS_ looks like a decent and quite involved effort.

Comment: Does UseTFS work with Atlassian OnDemand... i see atlassian have disabled their "Upload Plugin" link until Mid 2013, do you have to upload the plugin into Jira or can it be installed via the marketplace directly?

Comment: @MikeW Unfortunately "Plugins 3" (which is base for building on-demand plugins) is still in beta phase and not available to Atlassian customers. Hopefully it'll be released soon, and UseTFS for On-Demand will be available right after this happens.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently it's not a huge priority for Atlassian:

http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-1950

Comment: @vikasde - perhaps it's a business opportunity?  JIRA has a well documented API...

Answer (score 5):

I've succeeded to integrate TFS and Atlassian Fisheye / Crucible through SvnBridge. It works like a charm. There are couple of additional steps:

- You should implement patch 8517 (http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/patches) and build SvnBridge with it;
- You should change SVNKit version in FishEye. FishEye uses 1.3.3 version of SVNKit which doesn't work with SvnBridge (there are some PROPFIND errors). You should download 1.3.7 version from http://svnkit.com/ and put it into FishEye.

After that everything should work. 
There is one more optional patch for SvnBridge which prevents some error logs on server.

But eventually everything works perfect!

You can contact me for binaries and instructions...

Answer (score 2):

I looked for something like this a while ago and couldn't find anything.  I also talked to Atlassian developers directly and they didn't know of nothing that could help either.

That said, I ended up writing a custom integration piece for my customer to create TFS items from Jira items and then have the TFS status updates reflected back into Jira. It took just over a day to build so it's fairly straight forward to do assuming you know a bit of Java and both the Jira API (I used the XMLRPC interface) and TFS API's. Due to the way both systems work it required building a small middleware piece to listen for events from TFS and also to act as a REST end point for a custom action in Jira to call when the user clicked a "send to TFS" button.

Apart from that it was a case of adding some custom fields to the work item definitions on both sides to hold the cross reference values and then doing the mapping of values from one item to the other.

Unfortunately I don't have the code to share since it's on the customer site, otherwise I'd throw what I have up on a gist for you to look at.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SVN Bridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) to provide an SVN interface over your TFS installation.  Then set up Jira / FishEye as if it was an SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TFS Integration Platform. However there is no adapter for JIRA yet, however using the TFS Integration Platform (and I assume a good easy API JIRA has) means it shouldn't be too hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

I created a project a while back on this topic which may come handy for you.
It's released on github. feel free to branch it and make changes.

https://github.com/mahpour/TFSToJira